# How do I rename paths in webmatrix without editing a config file?

Tags: webmatrix

Microsoft Webmatrix 3 requires me to modify applicationhost.config in order to edit the path of a website. When I create a New Website, it automatically defaults its path folder name as EmptySite or EmptySite#, depending on what sites are already in the system according to the config. I do not see a way to fix that, other than modifying the config file directly. Every single site created will have this folder name, and it cannot be changed through the application. The site name does change, but that causes the other problem:
Webmatrix 3 does not delete sites from the config when a site is deleted in the program, so I cannot rename one site "This Site" once, delete it, then try to rename another site to "This Site". It will say a site with that name exists, yet it doesn't, simply because it does according to the config. I haven't found a solution other than to edit that file, which is an action that shouldn't have to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the applicationhost.config file is the only option available to you. If you think WebMatrix should offer better options, post some suggestions: https://webmatrix.uservoice.com/forums/128313-webmatrix-suggestions.

Just don't hold your breath.